# Ambiente para execução de HTML e PHP fora do Navegador

Tags: php, html

Há alguns anos encontrei um software que provia um ambiente para execução de aplicações HTML+PHP+Javascript fora do navegador. Por exemplo, era possível desenvolver uma aplicação nessas linguagens (suportava, além do PHP, o Ruby e o Python, se não me engano) e executava como se fosse um programa qualquer do Windows.

Ocorre que estou precisando desse software mas não consigo mais encontrar, pois não lembro o nome do projeto.

Alguém saberia o nome dessa aplicação ou outra que faça a mesma coisa?

Comment: É so um chute mas seria o gtk?

Comment: Primeiro coisa que eu pensei ao ler o titulo @rray http://gtk.php.net/

Comment: Não é o GTK. É algo como abrir uma aplicação HTML no chrome com o parâmetro APP e com um servidor web e o php já embutidos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenho quase certeza que esta se referindo ao https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop

Eu acho que ele não é totalmente independente, requer ou Chrome ou Internet Explorer embarcados:

- Download Chrome: https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/wiki/Download-Chrome
- Download MSIE: https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/wiki/Download-MSIE

### Como criar a sua primeira aplicação

1. Baixe o [PHP Desktop](https://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/#Downloads) (Chrome ou Internet Explorer)
2. Crie uma pasta chamada `meuaplicativo`
3. Extraia o conteudo do *PHP Desktop* dentro desta pasta, deve ficar assim:

   [image: pasta]
4. Abra o `phpdesktop-chrome.exe` ou `phpdesktop-msie.exe` (depende da versão que instalou), vai abrir uma tela assim:

   [image: php desktop msie]

Para desativar a tela do console precisa localizar o `settings.json` e trocar o `show_console` para `false`:

```
"debugging": {
    "show_console": false,
    "subprocess_show_console": false,
    "log_level": "DEBUG4",
    "log_file": "debug.log"
}
```

Para alterar a aplicação altere os arquivos dentro da pasta `www`.

### Como funciona:

Ele incorpora todos os serviços que seu aplicativo pode precisar antes de executar. Os principais elementos são o servidor web ([Mongoose](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/)), PHP e o banco de dados Sqlite. Ele incorpora um navegador (na verdade, Chrome ou Internet Explorer):

[image: PHP Desktop]

---

> **Nota:** Também encontrei este https://sourceforge.net/projects/html5phpdesktop/, eu não sei se são a mesma coisa, mas o primeiro link esta mais atualizado.

Comment: Poderia justificar o downvote? Aonde posso melhorar?